# Hexa to decimal conversion in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unpack, hex

I have  `"\001\022"`  as value of a. my desired decimal  value is 274.

I tried following function . but I get ["0112"]

```
a.unpack("H*")  ==>  ["0112"]
```

When I convert this "0112" to decimal using calculator it gives me 274. How can i get like
this using ruby methods.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format string in your question: "H*", is for "hex string (high nibble first)". Therefore it decoded your string as an array of 4-bit hexadecimal elements.

You need a different format.

Try this, which decodes it as a "16-bit unsigned, network (big-endian) byte order" integer:

```
a.unpack("n") # => [274]
```

For full details on what characters you can use in the format string, check the [Ruby Documentation for String#unpack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-unpack).